Can you be charged with incitement for using reverse psychology to get someone to commit a crime?
Let's say an online service makes an unpopular business decision, and people are coming up with ways to protest the change. If I tell someone to download LOIC (a network stress testing tool that is often used in denial-of-service attacks) and DDoS (distributed denial-of-service) the company's website, and someone actually does, then I would likely end up in hot water because DDOS attacks are very illegal.
But suppose I said something like this instead: "Protest however you want to. Just don't download LOIC and DDoS the company's website, because that's illegal. Which is unfortunate because a DDoS would send a very strong message."
And let's say someone or some people decide to participate in a DDoS attack because they saw my message. Would I still get in trouble in this scenario?
I do know some businesses sold "grapes bricks" during Prohibition and provided information on how not to make wine. To my knowledge, no one was ever convicted for doing this. However, that was a hundred years ago, so it wouldn't surprise me if relevant laws have changed since then.

I know what DDoS is (distributed denial of service: mass online attack), and so can guess that LOIC is some kind of software/platform for initiating such attacks, but it would be better to spell such things out in your question.

The answer will depend on where in the world you live, and also very much on the details of the case. If you were to employ verbal trickery, that could go to trial with an uncertain outcome.

@TripeHound I've edited the question to include links to their respective Wikipedia articles. Is that adequate?

You should include the meaning of the abbreviations in the question itself so readers don't need to visit a third party site to understand your question. As a general rule when using abbreviations you should always spell them out the first time they are used.

If you had intent and a reasonable expectation that your words would cause someone to commit the crime, I think you're liable.

The meaning of the statement is context specific, but I have a hard time reading that as any form of incitement. The first two sentences certainly wouldn't qualify. and, without a rich context beyond the question it is hard to say that even the third would be fairly read as an incitement, solicitation, conspiracy, or threat.

DDoS is often misused by laymen (example, your opening paragraph). The term you are looking for is just DoS, especially since as your example mentions, you're executing an attack by yourself and not in concert.

@uberhaxed Wikipedia says it's considered a DDoS if an attacker uses many systems. It's not impossible for a single person (such as a rogue sysadmin) to deploy and run the software on multiple computers. However, I did update the example to include the possibility of more than one person deciding to take action after seeing my message.

@Danny I think you're missing the nuance in why a DDoS attack is effective and why a few people following these instructions is not a DDoS attack. In a DDoS attack the objective is to make it not obvious that it's an attack, making it indistinguishable from normal usage. This requires a lot (e.g. million) of machines sending a few requests, not a few (e.g. hundreds) machines sending a lot of requests. This is typically why DDoS attacks are done by machines infected with a virus and why a dosen people with hundreds of computers each is not a DDoS (and probably can't even DOS with those numbers)

canada
In Canada, "incitement" refers to a particular hate-related offence. I think you're referring to what in Canada is called "counselling" of an offence, criminalized at s. 22 of the Criminal Code.

Where a person counsels another person to be a party to an offence and that other person is afterwards a party to that offence, the person who counselled is a party to that offence...

Even if the offence is not ultimately committed, so there is no offence to become a party to, the counselling itself is an independent, standalone offence, created at s. 464 of the Criminal Code:

every one who counsels another person to commit an indictable offence is, if the offence is not committed, guilty of an indictable offence and liable to the same punishment to which a person who attempts to commit that offence is liable

To prove someone guilty through counselling, the Crown must prove:

that the statement alleged to be "counselling" actually would persuade or induce the commission of the offence
that the accused intended the statement to have that effect, or knew of the risk that it would bring about the commission of the offence.

Without many more facts, we cannot know whether the circumstances you describe would constitute counselling.
